# Conflict with facebook app

Tags: android, debugging, crash

sorry for my english.

I made my first app very simple (web view with splash screen) for try and understand something basic function of android programming.

But when I build app-debug (directly on my smartphone), facebook start to crash continually.

I tried to leave only basic structure, commenting the rest

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

but, facebook continue to crash.
[This](http://nopaste.linux-dev.org/?586226) is the log.

Someone can help me about this funny/annoyng issue?

This is activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/sad_android"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="80dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewSplash"
    android:src="@drawable/splash"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
   />
```

Comment: and why do you care if facebook crash or not is it related to your application ?

Comment: can you post your activity_main.xml? If you are not doing anything except just setting the layout, i guess, it must have been some view declaration in the xml.

Comment: @1Dan normally in your logcat you would see that alot from facebook or twitter or any other application running in background if you are not doing anything related to facebook in your app don't worry about that

Comment: @AhmedBasyouny I don't know, but if I uninstall my app and clear facebook data,  it works fine. When I install again my app, returns same  problem. :(

Comment: I don't think it concern you that facebook is crash in background due to some reasons you and I don't know and don't even bother yourself about that